# (Comic) Foo-works

Tags: etymology

I know quite a lot of "-works" works in comic (["Wetworks"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetworks_(comics)), to name just one). Is this meme (or how you want to call it) comic-specific? And who brought it up?

The most simple theory would be that (stumbled over that while wikiing) "wetworks" is a Russian slang term for bloody murder, the above comic took it and then everybody jumped the works wagon. I am not convinced due to "Wetworks" not being extremely popular.

Comment: I can't think of any comic book series called "...works".  It seems likely that that comic alludes to the "murder/assassination" meaning.  I'm not really sure what you are talking about when you say "a lot of '-works' works"

Comment: Russian slang is wetwork (no 's'). You can use a -work ending to say something about a type of task or job - homework, woodwork, shiftwork, nightwork, daywork. Wetwork is wet because blood is spilled.

Comment: You often find the -works (with a final 's') in the name of e.g. software products, companies, etc, like 'Textworks' 'Imageworks' 'Musicworks', etc. 'Wetworks' says 'This is connected with violence and death'. It is the name of a team of special agents involved in risky activity. Also it is a cool name in comic terms as it is alliterative (two Ws).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: THX, this info at least burst my bubble that it's comic-specific. Unfortunately, I never made a list (although a few days ago I ran into yet another one), so I can only offer "Skunkworks", but even that was borrowed from the military term.

Comment: In former times, and sometimes still today, in Britain, and maybe the US, buildings, factories, or sites where certain industries were carried on were called a 'works', singular noun ending in 's'. An iron works, a steel works, a cement works and so on. You did not want to live in the part of a town where the gas works was located (smell, fumes). Over time one-word alternatives arose (e.g. 'gasworks'). The secret plane factory run by Lockheed was the 'Skunk Works' (two words). of course they didn't make or process skunks there; it was a cover name derived from a comic, in fact (Li'l Abner).

Comment: In Britain, the plant and facilities used by a water supply company may be called the 'water works' or 'waterworks'. A person who is suspected of crying, weeping, etc, rather too conveniently, e.g. to deflect blame or criticism, or for attention, may be accused of 'turning on the waterworks'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: As I evidently was too myopic (I'm a comic fan; also I am a German with limited vocabulary) - could you condense your comments to an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Russian slang for paid murder is allegedly, wetwork (no 's').

You can use a -work ending to say something about a type of task or job - homework, woodwork, shiftwork, nightwork, daywork. Wetwork is wet because blood is wet, and often spilled during a killing.

You often find the -works (with a final 's') in the name of e.g. software products, companies, etc, like 'Textworks' 'Imageworks' 'Musicworks', etc. 'Wetworks' says 'This is connected with violence and death'. It is the name of a team of special agents involved in risky activity. Also it is a cool name in comic terms as it is alliterative (two Ws).

In former times, and sometimes still today, in Britain, and maybe the US, buildings, factories, or sites where certain industries were carried on were called a 'works', singular noun ending in 's'. An iron works, a steel works, a cement works and so on. You did not want to live in the part of a town where the gas works was located (smell, fumes). Over time one-word alternatives arose (e.g. 'gasworks'). The secret plane factory run by Lockheed was the 'Skunk Works' (two words). of course they didn't make or process skunks there; it was a cover name derived from a comic, in fact (Li'l Abner).

It is possible, of course, that the 'wetworks' team name is a cover in the same way.

In Britain, the plant and facilities used by a water supply company may be called the 'water works' or 'waterworks'. A person who is suspected of crying, weeping, etc, rather too conveniently, e.g. to deflect blame or criticism, or for attention, may be accused of 'turning on the waterworks'.